# Is it possible for hpc cluster node to directly read and write to openio sds(or distributed file system) and still achieve the max performance

Tags: hdfs, bigdata, hpc

Is it possible for a node of a **HPC** cluster to directly read and write to **openio sds** (or some other distributed file system)?

I assume we need to first pull the input data and code to the hpc node and process it. And with this we could get best of what computing resource we have.

I am wondering what if we just put code in **HPC** and directly read and write data from/to distributed file system which is in the same network with high bandwidth NIC. By this way, I think the network may be bottle neck as it may not match the processing speed of **HPC** node.

Do **HPC cloud service from google and amazon** directly read and write to their distributed file system?

Please shed some insights. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

> "I assume we need to first pull the input data and code to the hpc
> node and process it. And with this we could get best of what computing
> resource we have."

This is correct. You are best off keeping your data as close to that which is processing it. Pulling your data from a  distributed filesystem first and processing from RAM will be far more performant than processing directly from the filesystem.
Obviously this is not always possible, for instance you have a large table you want to process but is larger than local memory. This is where HPC programming techniques will come to your aid as well as taking advantage of the distributed filesystem. For example, Lustre allows you to spread data over multiple OSTs and metadata over multiple MDTs to boost IO performance.

Comment: Could you enlighten us, how could any DATA be processed (w/o having been,prior to that "processing",first pre-fetched from some filesystem storage-resources (be it SSD, NVM, disk, tape, optical-archive, whatever physical device) and stored in RAM) in contrast of *(cit.)* "*processing from RAM*" as compared to  *(cit.)* "*[less performant] processing directly from the filesystem*"? Any localhost filesystem in use was since ever a localhost in-RAM abstraction of something else (be it a real file,symlink'ed file,a pipe,an in-RAM maintained set of CPU+O/S counters)...so again in-RAM -vs- in-RAM?

Comment: Would you agree that (*cit.*) "*boost[ing] IO performance*" is the same or something different than a (just) latency-masking ( without any performance boosted ), when the metadata got spread somewhat closer to the processor, while the actual data not? Input-Output performance remains the same, doesn't it? If not, where did it the data-flow get any accelerated performance from? A mere population of replicated metadata does not have any effect on the flow-of-data ( the Input-Output flow performance ). It may "reduce" access-type blocking bottlenecks (as more resources added into different paths)

Comment: I think I understand your question. I guess it really depends on the I/O profile of the job and type of job in question. If you have a file which is processed sequentially, then yes you will probably see little performance increase using the method I suggest above. However, say you have a file which requires access at random parts within the file. Doing this sort of I/O within RAM (or even tmpfs) by reading the entire contents of the file off the distributed filesystem at job startup is far more performant than doing it directly from a distributed filesystem at runtime.

Comment: Regarding your second comment, i fully agree. However, in my answer I stated that Lustre allows you to both spread Metadata over MDTs and actual data over the OSTs. Again, understanding the I/O profile of the job is critical in understanding the best use of the infrastructure to return the best performance.